# Prevent Internet Explorer 8 from exiting when closing the last tab

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Firefox doesn't exit when I close the last tab, just by doing some customization in `about:config`. But now, my company has to work with some website that only works well on Internet Explorer. I currently use Internet Explorer 8 on Windows XP SP3.
So, how do I prevent Internet Explorer 8 from exiting when closing the last tab?
I've searched for such a feature for a while but found nothing helpful.

---

FYI
I gave up with my "customization habit", now I'm trying to live with IE world, ... phew...

Comment: The obvious question is why leave a program running that isn't doing anything?

Comment: On my IE8, it's not possible to close the last tab.  There's no X on the tab, and the "Close tab" option is grayed out on the right-click menu - after you close the second-to-the-last tab.

Comment: @uSlackr:
my Firefox just open-a-new-blank-tab when I close the last tab.

Comment: @bwall: on my IE8, I can use Ctrl+W or Alt+F+C to close the last tab, so I posted this question.

Comment: Why not just manually open a blank tab before closing the last tab?  Or open a blank tab when the browser starts, and just never close it, or use it.

Comment: @Zoredache: because I love the life with Firefox, I can do everything I want, the question just about time & knowledge. And now, I'm pushed to forgot that life.
And thanks to `yesterday` !

Comment: It's not exactly what you're looking for, but press CTRL+T and then CTRL+W in succession. It will open a new tab and close the current one. (If it closes the new one, it's an option in Tools/Internet Options/General/Tabs:Settings/Unecheck 'Always switch to new tabs when they are created'.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many tries then I found that there is no way to do this thing!
Finally, I gave up with my "customization habit", now I'm trying to live with IE world, ... (:-|)

Answer (score 1):

Consider switching to Firefox, it can be configured to leave last tab open and fill it with the default home page, a blank page, or your original home page (since I use DuckDuckGo search as my home page, this is convenient).

For IE -- Just open a home page as your second page in IE before closing the remaining page.